# Класс, в методе this === undefined

Tags: javascript, классы, ecmascript-6

Вопрос в коде:

```
class Target {
    constructor() {
        ...
        /*Следующий код передает функцию обработчик события через одну библиотеку,   не важно что за библиотека, проблема в том что в this.targetOnMousedown я не могу получить ссылку на объект класса, то есть не могу что-то делать с объектом, this === undefined*/
        this.target.on('mousedown', this.targetOnMousedown);
    }

    targetOnMousedown() {
        /*this не ссылается на объект Target, тут я например хочу сделать this.apples = 5;*/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this зависит от контекста.
Чтобы указать контекст используйте .bind()

```
this.target.on('mousedown', this.targetOnMousedown.bind(this));
```